# php+sql help me please

Tags: php, sql

This code is working fine.

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO EventTest (name,text,lat,lon,date,time,type,number,adress) VALUES ('$name','$text','$lat','$lon','$date','$time','$type','$number','$address')";
    $sth = $con->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
```

I've added this code after the previous block.

```
    $sql1 = "SELECT id FROM EventTest ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $sth1 = $con->prepare($sql1);
    $sth1->execute();
    $sth1->bind_result($id)
    while($sth1->fetch()) {     
    $data['YES'] = $id;
    }
```

The table has all the fields.
This code is not working.

I can't recieve the error from the server.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Don't build SQL by variable interpolation. Use bound parameters!

Comment: at the test errors are not sent to the client

Comment: You need to check the PHP error log on the server. It's ridiculous that a simple missing semicolon gets posted as a SQL question.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to check the error log for this. Any decent IDE will show you this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a single error, so I'll make a bet, and provide a short answer.

Add a semicolon at the end of this line :

```
$sth1->bind_result($id);
```